# Is it possible to use Google Cloud Endpoints built in authentication with Google+ Domains API?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints, google-plus-domains

Google Cloud Endpoints has it's own authentication process in which the backend endpoint method is simply passed a `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` object.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

The Google+ Domains API specifies its own authentication process in order to get the `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential` object. This allows for the building of the `com.google.api.services.plusDomains.PlusDomain` object.

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/

How would you integrate these two authentication processes? This is for a **web app** (Java Script) with a Google App Engine (Java) backend.

In an ideal situation, I would like to be able to retrieve the users bio/profile basic info via my JS app while the user is offline.

Use Case: I have a comment thread where each comment has an author persisted in the Google Datastore as a `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` object. However when I render the comment thread in my JS web app I would like to show a profile picture for each author. If I could make a call from the web app to retrieve the bio for each commenter I could save the backend a lot of work. The web app would have the user object as JSON. Which includes the user ID and email.

Comment: Can you add some details on your use case? Normally you would pass the user object to an endpoint, then, when user is identified, on endpoint use a service account acting on behalf of this user.

Comment: @NikitaUchaev I have the standard Endpoints authentication set up. Passing the user object as you said. Want to get a bio for the user. What do you mean "service account acting on behalf of this user"? Can you link some code or documentation?

Comment: @NikitaUchaev I see what you mean about the question being unclear. I updated the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom authenticator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your use-case is:

- your users authenticate to your app, granting the basic userinfo.profile scope needed to get the `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` object properly received in your endpoints API
- you persist these User objects to the DB, and when you retrieve them to display the thread they commented in, you'd like to make a call to the google+ API [people.get method](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) to retrieve their avatar image URL

The solution: if your users were presented with an oauth flow that had them  grant [the scope required](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes) for the google+ API call (the `profile` scope) in addition to the regular endpoints "userinfo.profile" scope, it should be no problem to call the Google+ API, either from the [JS](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) client or from the [Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) back-end, using the Google API client libraries, after going through that flow to obtain the credentials.

In order to avoid re-authenticating them each time, you should [serialize and store a credentials object from the language in question](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials), or you could even simply keep track of the refresh token for their grant and go through the low-level OAuth dance to obtain a fresh access token (you'll probably want to do the former, as it does this for you).

As noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280588/google-cloud-endpoints-usergetuserid-different-than-profile-id-on-google) on the web (in several other places as well), the userid [from the User object](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User#getUserId()) is not the same as the Google+ profile id, so be aware of that when working with the endpoints method parameter User objects. You therefore won't be able to use the userid from the User object to call `people.get`.

Instead, you should store the Google+ profile ID of the user at the time that they first [signed-in](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) or at least went through the oauth flow that granted the necessary Google+ scope, alongside the User object you've already been using. You'll have to use the (de)serialized credentials objects or refresh/access tokens to call the Google+ API, once you retrieve the Google+ profile id from each user's data model in your storage (whatever solution you use, from Datastore to SQL, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that the Google+ profile ID is not the same as the user's Google account ID.